# Bottom Navigation как скрыть на некоторых Fragmentах?

Tags: android, kotlin

В Activity имеется Bottom Navigation. Мне этот компонент не нужен на всех fragmentах, я хочу его там скрыть.

Как это можно сделать?

Я сейчас пытаюсь достучаться из Fragment

```
val nav = view.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)
nav.visibility = View.GONE
```

Ожидаемо падает

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.peshkariki/com.app.peshkariki.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: nav must not be null
```

Comment: nav_view находится в активности или в фрагменте, и как вы стучитесь?

Comment: @Andrew Он находится в activity. Как я понимаю, при запуске фрагмента, fragment_container, который лежит подменяется текущий Layout, поэтому я могу получить доступ и к Bottom Navigation, который дежит рядом, ведь это 1 layout получается, разве нет?

Comment: зачем findViewById? ипользуйте kotlinx.android.synthetic

Comment: requireActivity().nav_view.visibility = GONE и все

Comment: Тот кто владеет UI элементом, только тот и имеет право им манипулировать. Т.е. активити в вашем случае. Она же и фрагментами манипулирует, надеюсь. Вот манипулируйте всем вместе и в одном месте.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы вам советовал два варианта: попроще и посложнее.

1. При использовании нижнего меню на нужном вам фрагменте просто скрывайте нижнее меню как вы уже это сделали. Проблема в том что bottomNavigationView находится в разметке активности а не фрагмента. Поэтому приложение падает.
2. Второй вариант - использование интерфейса между активностью и фрагментом. То есть вы сделаете канал связи по которому из нужного вам фрагмента можно будет скрыть нижнее меню.

Answer (score 0):

В одном из своих проектов решил эту проблему достаточно просто. При создании `Activity`, которому принадлежит `BottomNavigationView` я сохраняю ссылку на это `Activity`, через которую смогу получить доступ к панели навигации, а саму навигацию делаю публичной. Далее во фрагментах, где не должно быть видно навигации при старте скрываю ее, а в остальных фрагментах при старте возврашаю обратно.